# java pst library

Tags: java, eclipse, pst

I'm wrinting Junit tests and for a specefic actions I need to give path the the java library "pst.dll"
I set it from eclipse->run config->VM arguments and I set the path to pst.dll
the problem is , I have to do it for each testcase otherwise I get :
`Exception in thread "Thread-13" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no pst in java.library.path`.
Is there a way to put the path to the pst.dll for all test cases? or for the project to avoid to add it each time ?
thanks.

Comment: There's a checkmark next to each answer. Simply highlight the checkmark next to that question that you liked most. The [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) provides more help on this topic.

Comment: thanks Andeas_D, I did it for two questions and I'll do it for the others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the VM options for the JRE you are using to execute the test cases in eclipse. Go to Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Installed Jre's and configure this option in the respective JDK/JRE.

Comment: Faisal,from eclipse I go to -> Installed Jre's -> in default VM arguments, which variable should I select? there is no "java_library" or something like this to set the path to the pst library ?

Comment: in Default VM arguments. Specify your argument as -Djava.library.path=YOUR PATH TO LIBRARY

For more information check this: http://help.eclipse.org/help33/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/preferences/java/debug/ref-installed_jres.htm